# Convert to UCS2

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Is there any function in Vb.net (or C#) that encodes a string in UCS2?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Use the following functions to encode unicode string in "UCS2" format:

```
    //================> Used to encoding GSM message as UCS2
    public static String UnicodeStr2HexStr(String strMessage)
    {
        byte[] ba = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(strMessage);
        String strHex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
        strHex = strHex.Replace("-", "");
        return strHex;
    }

    public static String HexStr2UnicodeStr(String strHex)
    {
        byte[] ba = HexStr2HexBytes(strHex);
        return HexBytes2UnicodeStr(ba);
    }

    //================> Used to decoding GSM UCS2 message  
    public static String HexBytes2UnicodeStr(byte[] ba)
    {
        var strMessage = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(ba, 0, ba.Length);
        return strMessage;
    }

    public static byte[] HexStr2HexBytes(String strHex)
    {
        strHex = strHex.Replace(" ", "");
        int nNumberChars = strHex.Length / 2;
        byte[] aBytes = new byte[nNumberChars];
        using (var sr = new StringReader(strHex))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nNumberChars; i++)
                aBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(new String(new char[2] { (char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read() }), 16);
        }
        return aBytes;
    }
```

for example:

```
String strE = SmsEngine.UnicodeStr2HexStr("سلام به گچپژ پارسي");
// strE = "0633064406270645002006280647002006AF0686067E06980020067E062706310633064A"
String strD = SmsEngine.HexStr2UnicodeStr("0633064406270645002006280647002006AF0686067E06980020067E062706310633064A");
// strD = "سلام به گچپژ پارسي"
```

Comment: Thanks. But I can not see Hex2ByteArray method implementation?

Comment: Thanks. it seams your are quiet experienced about SMS category. Can I Ask if it is possible to send SMS with more than 70 char length?

Comment: @BehzadEbrahimi Thank you very much for this wonderful solution. It solved a problem that I worked on for 3 consecutive days.

Comment: This is not UCS-2, this is UTF-16. Similar, but not the same.

Answer (score 7):

No, .NET supports the full Unicode range for strings and many encodings that derive from [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx). You can [trivially get UTF-16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx), but not UCS-2. However, if you first get rid of all surrogate pairs in the input string, then UTF-16 *is* UCS-2. But there's no built-in encoding that does that for you.

Comment: How likely is it he'll ever come across any characters out of the first plane, though? Or fonts to display them?

Comment: Rup: Without knowing context that's hard to tell. Many of my Word documents have large amounts of Plane 1 characters (remember: the math Latin alphabets are there), albeit the other astral planes are somewhat rare, indeed. In any case, if they specifically ask for UCS-2 I'd assume they know the difference to UTF-16 and also know why they need UCS-2. In the end it's not for us to speculate whether or whether not comething else would be right here :-)

Answer (score 1):

See [`Encoding.Unicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx).

Given a .NET `String`, call [`Encoding.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx) to get a byte array representing that string encoded in UCS2.

**Edit:** In the context of `System.Text.Encoding`, Unicode = UTF-16. As Johannes points out, these are not the same thing in the presence of surrogates.

Answer (score 0):

I think String.Normalize() will do what you want.

```
String.Normalize()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netframework-4.8