# Send USSD code to modem in C# and ERROR in return always

Tags: c#, decode, at-command, modem, ussd

I am sending USSD code on modem through serial port. But always it is giving ERROR in response.

AT commands I am sending are:
in sequence:

```
serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=0" + "\r\n");
serialPort.Write("AT+CUSD=1,\"*135#\"" + "\r\n");
```

when I am configuring message format in first AT command, it is giving 'OK' response. But on sending USSD code, response is always 'ERROR'. Why is it so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `\n` in end of command, use only `\r`.

Form of CUSD command is: `AT+CUSD=1,"*135#",15`.

In C# it should be:

```
serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=0" + "\r");
serialPort.Write("AT+CUSD=1,\"*135#\",15" + "\r");
```

Comment: This is correct, always terminate AT command lines with just `\r`.

Answer (score 3):

First, AT command is ended by "\r" in C#.
You may also to check TE Character set of your modem.

```
serialPort.Write("AT+CSCS?\r");
```

if Character Set is "UCS2" use the following conversation:

```
serialPort.Write("AT+CUSD=1,\"" + UnicodeStr2HexStr("*135#") + "\",15" + "\r");
```

And

```
public static String UnicodeStr2HexStr(String strMessage)
{
    byte[] ba = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(strMessage);
    String strHex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
    strHex = strHex.Replace("-", "");
    return strHex;
}
```

Please see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25155746/638977 (Convert to UCS2)

Comment: how to reconvert the hex to Str again