# How to send bulk SMS that contain Unicode characters?

Tags: c#, bulksms

I'm am working with bulk SMS application. It works fine, but when I send a message with Unicode characters, my mobile shows it as *????????*.

I am using a XML file that contains URL, numbers and message body.

The code I have is this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Method = "POST";
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 41.0.2228.0 Safari / 537.36";
request.Accept = "text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.ContentLength > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
    {
        returnValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
else
{
    returnValue = "ERROR" + " " + "No Response From Jasmin";
}

Console.WriteLine(returnValue);
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Hope you guys give me a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

SMS uses the UCS-2 character set for unicode characters (16 bits per char, so your maximum length is halved). If your source string isn't ASCII compatible then you need to convert to UCS-2. For how to do that, see [Convert to UCS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438340/convert-to-ucs2/25155746#25155746)

Comment: Tried that. but the result is same.

Comment: Are you sure that the API you are using is capable of sending Unicode characters?

Comment: yes.. i passed values directly to the URL that time it worked. when i tried to passed values through XML is doesn't worked.

Comment: So the problem would appear to be with your XML then. Are you sure that it is being saved as UTF-8 rather than ASCII?

Comment: Here is my XML file                                                                                           <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><message><submit><da><number>94712440802</number></da><oa><number>94115753753</number></oa><ud>ඔබ තෝරන භාෂාවෙන් ටයිප් කිරීම</ud><statusrequest><dlr-mask>63</dlr-mask><coding>2</coding></statusrequest><from><username>********</username><password>********</password></from></submit></message>

Comment: So what do you send to the API if you call it directly?

Comment: [URL]
username=username&
password=password&
to=94712440802&
from=94115753753&
priority=0&
text=test&
coding=2&
charset=utf-8

Comment: So why don't you transform the XML into that format (which includes the character set in use in case you haven't noticed) and send the transformed version?